# Jmeter - Fetch the Session ID from the Response and pass it next request.Request & Responses are in JSON

Tags: json, automation, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

Scenario :-
Im performing Load testing using API's

HTTP Request 1

I logged in using http://cabhound.com:1000/v2/driver/login and I got the below response

```
{"statusCode":200,"statusMessage":"Success","errorMessage":"","responseData":{"id":0,"userName":"PQeurentraps5S@tarento.com","firstName":"Partner","lastName":"Tarento","phoneNumber":"2641148625","email":"tamvrentrapnsr@tarento.com","password":"","addressOne":"","addressTwo":"","city":"","state":"","zipCode":"","loginCount":156,"welcome":"","smsOptIn":false,"promoCode":"","userNotification":"","errorMessage":"","message":"","sessionId":"6063tnerLt3013951671120oDse18492930#2","osType":"","osVersion":"","deviceType":"","deviceId":"","latitude":"","longitude":"","timeZone":"","appVersion":"","company":"Tarento","licenceNumber":"","vehicleType":"","vehicleFeature":null,"subscriptionType":"unlimited","driverWorkingCity":"Bangalore","vehicleNumber":"","locationUpdateTime":20,"rate":0,"reliable":0,"distance":0.0,"eta":0,"latitudeLongitude":"","status":"ON","payment":{"paymentType":"","cardNumber":"","cvnNumber":"","expDate":""},"vehicleTypeList":["Sedan","Limousine","SUV/Wagon","Minivan","Other"],"vehicleFeatureList":["Navigation System","Eco Friendly","Handicap accessible","Accepts credit cards"],"driverId":582,"currentLocation":null,"companyCode":"tarento","acceptanceRate":0,"like":0,"profileIndicator":0,"payWithCabHound":false,"smsSupport":false,"paymentInfo":false,"geoInfo":"","active":true}}
```

Please see the session id in the above response,which I want to use in next http request data

HTTP Request 2

http://cabhound.com:1000/v2/driver/dutyStatus

Below is the data which I need to post,here I want to use session id of HTTP Request 1

```
{"status":"ON","sessionId":"1311tnerLt9013956793297oDse462783#2","longitude":"77.686700","userName":"erpkrentrapJps@tarento.com","latitude":"12.934487"}
```

How to pass the session id of HTTP Request 1 (response) to HTTP Request 2 Post Data

Help me in this which I have strucked

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) available through [JMeter Plugin](http://jmeter-plugins.org/downloads/all/) (you'll need Extras with Libs Set.

Regex are headache to develop, especially for JSON data which can be multiline. Beanshell has known performance issues, so using a plugin is the best option.

Relevant JSON Path query for your sessionId will look as:

```
$.responseData.sessionId
```

See `Parsing JSON` section of Using the [XPath Extractor in JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) guide for more details and XPath to JSON Path mapping

Comment: Using JSON Path Extractor I have extracted the sessionId and stored in SessionCH.Now I have to pass this into next Http Request - I tried to pass like this {"status":"ON",${SessionCH},"longitude":"77.686700","userName":"erpkrentrapJps@tarento.com","latitude":"12.934487"} but it throwed error

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 solutions for above problem,

1. Use Regular expression extractor to extract the value (I haven't used it with json response but I think it will work)
2. Use Beanshell preprocessor or postprocessor in which you can get response and find required sessionID using substr or json parsers or use simple java code. Extract the required value and use it in next request.

Comment: for Regex see jmeter help, for beanshell you can refer http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell or http://capacitas.wordpress.com/2012/10/31/using-the-power-of-java-programming-in-your-jmeter-scripts-beanshell/